# Javascript Jquery - Change table cell colors upon checkbox click

Tags: javascript, jquery, matrix, checkbox, html-table

I am creating a **crossing matrix** where I would cross entries; like male and female. I did this using a dynamically generated table where each cell pertains to a cross of a female.

Looks like this :

```
Female/Male | Male1 | Male2 |
------------------------------
Female1     |   x   |   x   |
------------------------------
Female2     |   x   |   x   |
-----------------------------
```

Above is a table, each cell contains a checkbox to identify the cross.

Below is the code i used to generate the table using php:

```
<table>
<?php
    foreach($females...){
       echo "<tr>";
       ...so on
       //set up the rows and headers
       foreach($males...){
              echo "<td ...><input type='checkbox'../></td>
              ..and so on
       }    
    }

?>
</table>
```

I need to **color the cell like green or red, upon clicking the checkbox** that is in it. How do I do this in **Jquery/Javascript?** and also, how do I ID each cell, and know the value (cross) it pertains to? If it is dynamic- the number of males and females are **indefinite and changing** so that the number of cells and checkboxes are also indefinite?

Comment: What exactly goes in ...so on and ..and so on? Don't expect us to guess your code. Reproduce it in a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes you want to do green when checked, red when not.  You didn't exactly tell us which.

Find the parent of the checkbox.  I do this with parents() always because if an element gets added to the stack later on, your code gets screwed up and you don't know why.

```
<td ...><input type='checkbox' 
         onclick="$(this).parents('td').css('background-color', $(this).is(':checked') ? 'green' : 'red');" />
</td>
```

Add in escaped quotes where necessary to get this to work with php's echo command.